# How to find an element (button) without the ID, Value and Type using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<button class="button" style="styles">TEXT</button>
```

How do I find this element in a website using Selenium PhantomJS?

Comment: What do you mean find it without any indication? Is like looking for a person without knowing his/hers name/look/Id. Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529967/how-to-find-button-element-with-webdriver/39594489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XPATH, ro the element you want to find by using:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

myButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
```

But using the XPATH is not the best practice sinze it can change if the html changes.

Other way to lacate it is using the tag "button":

```
myButton = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
```

or the class:

```
myButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
```

There are several ways to find it, you can check them here:

[enter link description here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)